# Changing window layout in gtk2hs

Tags: user-interface, haskell, gtk2hs

I am making an applocation to demonstrate some algorithms, and I am using gtk2hs. When the user selects an algorithm, I want the whole window to change (different layout, input, output interface...). How could I do that? For example, is it possible to change the widget in a container? I tried a table but could not changed the content of a cell, so that doesn't seem like a good idea.
Also I want to change the number of input fields according to another input field, and that seems like the same problem for me (removing widgets from a box) but it might be totally different in terms of solution.
Thanks

Comment: This looks more like asking for a tutorial than asking a concrete question.

Comment: Ok. How to change the content of a box, can you delete a widget from it? If yes, how? (Or if you know a good tutorial where I can find the answer, that would help a lot too...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to change the content of a box, can you delete a widget from it? If yes, how?

Use `widgetDestroy`. See for example [this tutorial](http://projects.haskell.org/gtk2hs/docs/tutorial/glade/).